# Increasing RAM on a Virtual Server | Hyper V 2008 R2

Tags: memory, virtual-machine, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I have a Hyper V box that hosts 5 servers.

One server has 6GB of RAM (Server A) while another has 4GB of RAM (Server B).

Is it possible to take 2GB from Server A and place it into Server B in Hyper V?

Here's the memory settings of both servers on Hyper V Manager.

### Server A with 6GB RAM

[image]

### Server B with 4GB RAM

[image]

If this is possible, how would I do this?

If not, how can I upgrade Server B so it has 6GB of RAM?

**Edit:** The Hyper V Host has a total of 30GB RAM installed.

Comment: Just to clarify, you have one physical server with 5 guests, and Server A and Server B are both Guests?

Comment: By Guest do you mean are they Virtual machines? I have one Physical server (we'll call it Host) which is running 5 Virtual Machines (Server A+B+C+D+E).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the standard basic Hyper-V licencing you'll need to stop the servers before making the changes.

Using the Hyper-V management console:

- Stop both VMs.
- Edit their Settings.
- Reduce the allotted RAM on Server A.
- Increase the allotted RAM on Server B.
- Start the VMs again.